# Inferring the geometry of a complete bipartite 2D geometric graph from the edge lengths

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We have two sets of points in a 2D plane: $P = \{p_1, \cdots, p_m\}$ and $Q = \{q_1, \cdots, q_n\}$. All that is known is the distance between $p_i$ and $q_j$ for all $i, j$.

- What can one infer about the geometry of the points?
- If one constrains $p_1 = (0, 0)$ and $p_2 = (0, y)$, with $y \in \mathbb{R}$, can one infer or approximate the coordinates of the points?
- Is inferring the coordinates a tractable problem?

I was able to figure out that we can approximate the distance between two points in $Q$ using their respective distances to all of the points in $P$:

$$
\max_i{|m(p_i, q_a) - m(p_i, q_b)|} \le m(q_a, q_b) \le \min_i{m(p_i, q_a) + m(p_i, q_b)}
$$

where $m(p, q)$ is the distance between the points $p$ and $q$.

The context is that I'm helping someone out with a programming problem related to simultaneous localisation and mapping. I'm a programmer by trade and my mathematics is rather rusty!